# Prolog - Return result instead of printing in algorithm

Tags: algorithm, prolog, prolog-toplevel, logical-purity

I know there is technically no 'return' in Prolog but I did not know how to formulate the question otherwise.

I found some sample code of an algorithm for finding routes between metro stations. It works well, however it is supposed to just print the result so it makes it hard to be extended or to do a `findall/3` for example.

```
% direct routes
findRoute(X,Y,Lines,Output) :- 
    line(Line,Stations),
    \+ member(Line,Lines),
    member(X,Stations),
    member(Y,Stations),
    append(Output,[[X,Line,Y]],NewOutput),
    print(NewOutput).

% needs intermediate stop
findRoute(X,Y,Lines,Output) :- 
    line(Line,Stations),
    \+ member(Line,Lines),
    member(X,Stations),
    member(Intermediate,Stations),
    X\=Intermediate,Intermediate\=Y,
    append(Output,[[X,Line,Intermediate]],NewOutput),
    findRoute(Intermediate,Y,[Line|Lines],NewOutput).
```

`line` is a predicate with an atom and a list containing the stations.
For ex: `line(s1, [first_stop, second_stop, third_stop])`

So what I am trying to do is get rid of that `print` at line 11 and add an extra variable to my rule to store the result for later use. However I failed miserably because no matter what I try it either enters infinite loop or returns false.

Now:

```
?- findRoute(first_stop, third_stop, [], []).
% prints [[first_stop,s1,third_stop]]
```

Want:

```
?- findRoute(first_stop, third_stop, [], R).
% [[first_stop,s1,third_stop]] is stored in R
```

Comment: You really just need to add a new argument to `findRoute/4` and get rid of `print(NewOutput)`. Obviously, pick a name for the new argument that isn't already used in the predicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you, I also see this pattern frequently among Prolog beginners, especially if they are using bad books and other material:

```
solve :-
     .... some goals ...
     compute(A),
     write(A).
```

Almost every line in the above is problematic, for the following reasons:

1. "solve" is **imperative**. This does not make sense in a declarative languague like Prolog, because you can use predicates in several directions.
2. "compute" is also imperative.
3. `write/1` is a side-effect, and its output is only available on the system terminal. This gives us no easy way to actually **test** the predicate.

Such patterns should always simply look similar to:

```
solution(S) :-
     condition1(...),
     condition2(...),
     condition_n(S).
```

where `condition1` etc. are simply pure goals that describe what it means that `S` is a solution.

When querying

```
?- solution(S).
```

then bindings for `S` will **automatically be printed** on the toplevel. Let the toplevel do the printing for you!

In your case, there is a straight-forward fix: Simply make `NewOutput` one of the arguments, and remove the final side-effect:

```
route(X, Y, Lines, Output, NewOutput) :- 
    line(Line, Stations),
    \+ member(Line, Lines),
    member(X, Stations),
    member(Y, Stations),
    append(Output, [[X,Line,Y]], NewOutput).
```

Note also that I have changed the name to just `route/5`, because the predicate makes sense also *if the arguments are all already instantiated*, which is useful for testing etc.

Moreover, when describing lists, you will often benefit a lot from using [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) notation.

The code will look similar to this:

```
route(S, S, _) --> [].          % case 1: already there
route(S0, S, Lines) -->         % case 2: needs intermediate stop
    { line_stations(Line, Stations0),
      maplist(dif(Line), Lines),
      select(S0, Stations0, Stations),
      member(S1, Stations) },
    [link(S0,Line,S1)],
    route(S1, S, [Line|Lines]).
```

Conveniently, you can use this to describe the concatenation of lists without needing `append/3` so much. I have also made a few other changes to enhance purity and readability, and I leave figuring out the exact differences as an easy exercise.

You call this using the DCG interface predicate `phrase/2`, using:

```
?- phrase(route(X,Y,[]), Rs).
```

where `Rs` is the found route. Note also that I am using terms of the form `link/3` to denote the links of the route. It is good practice to use dedicated terms when the arity is known. Lists are for example good if you do not know beforehand how many elements you need to represent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I am also a beginner and I still don't know how to fix it. I tried the same thing as your first example: ```route(X, Y, Lines, Output, NewOutput) :- ``` but I don't know how to 'update' the second case with 5 arguments.

Comment: I recommend you simply go straight with the DCG version, since you do not need to think about so many variables with it. In the plain Prolog version, you can simply extend the second clause with a new variable, say `Route`, and extend the recursive call of `route` with exactly the same variable. You can think of this variable as only being threaded through to later report the route with it on the toplevel. Note though that this way to solve the task is quite botched in any case because you need `append/3` so much. DCGs allow you to do without `append/3`. More efficient **and** more readable!

Comment: yes, you are right... I can't believe it was so easy. I must've even tried something similar but stumbled in some typos where prolog was just returning false :). The dcg notation is pretty advanced for me at this point, but thank you for that as well.

Comment: Great, it is quite unusual for beginners to think as declaratively as you. You are definitely on the right track with this question! Excepting `ofCourseTheUnreadableNamingConvention`, where `using_underscores_is_much_more_readable`!

Comment: hehe, I somehow thought it is the standard in Prolog because vars start always with uppercase and ```New_result``` looks kinda' weird. Well I just woke up one morning (about a week ago) wanting to learn prolog and I must say I am amazed how easy some things are and how complicated the 'simple' ones are :)).

Comment: For variables, camelcase is indeed sometimes used, but never for predicates. And even for variables, you more often see better conventions like `State0`, `State1`, ... `State` to denote successive states. In your example, `Route0`, `Route1` and `Route` would be a good choice. Certainly better than `Route` and `NewRoute`.

Comment: cough `\+ member(`